# Total Time Taken Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

[image]

[image]

Distance of chord = [image]

Time taken to "swim" to the desalination plant = [image]

I'm stuck here! The textbook working out is as such:

[image]

I don't understand how they have the 'k' or 1/2

the runs river at 2 km per hour.... isn't this DL/Dx=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tasmania runs from the camp at $(0, 0)$ to a point $(x, x^2 - 1)$ on the parabola $y = x^2 - 1$.  This distance, in km, is

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{(x - 0)^2 + (x^2 - 1 - 0)^2} & = \sqrt{x^2 + (x^2 - 1)^2}\\
                                   & = \sqrt{x^2 + x^4 - 2x^2 + 1}\\
                                   & = \sqrt{x^4 - x^2 + 1}
\end{align*}

Since he runs at a rate of $2~\text{km}/\text{h}$, the time (measured in hours) required to run from the camp to the river is

$$t = \frac{d}{v} = \frac{\sqrt{x^4 - x^2 + 1}}{2}$$

As for the $k$, remember that the time he takes to swim up the river is proportional to the difference in the $y$-coordinates.  The constant $k > 0$ is the constant of proportionality.

Comment: thanks! D = S*T is what i had forgotten